# Cannot read property 'unsubscribe' of undefined

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework

i have a ionic project.

I want to unsubscribe when i get the cities from subscription of firebase return.

But something goes wrong and it throws following error when i try to unsubscribe.

How can is solve that?

My code.

```
getCities() {
let i: any;
let a = this.firebaseProvider.getOtoparks()
  .subscribe(data => {
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      this.cities.push({
          name: data[i]['details']['sehir'],
          value: i,
        }
      );
    }
    // try to unsubscribe
    a.unsubscribe();
  });
}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems like you're trying to get the data only ONCE. Unsubscribing in the subscribe isn't the best practice imho. Try getOtoparks().take(1).subscribe(... without the a.unsubscribe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is to use take(1) when you want to unsubscribe without a condition.

```
getCities() {
     let i: any;
     let a = this.firebaseProvider.getOtoparks()
         .take(1)
         .subscribe(data => {
             for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                 this.cities.push({
                     name: data[i]['details']['sehir'],
                     value: i,
                 });
             }
         });
}
```